# LiveAuthException at Login to OneDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am trying to connect to OneDrive via the c# sdk.

```
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient(_clientId, new RefreshTokenHandler(authToken));
LiveLoginResult liveLoginResult = authClient.InitializeAsync(new[] { "wl.skydrive_update", "wl.offline_access" }).Result;
```

On the **authClient.InitializeAsync()** I receive an **Microsoft.Live.LiveAuthException** with the Message

> The provided request must include a 'client_secret' input parameter.

So where should i set the client_secret and why?